# How to choose Dev devices Permissions

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, file-permissions

In my exercise I'm supposed to write a kernel module with /dev with read only permission. In my code I have:

```c
static DEVICE_ATTR(name_att, S_IRUSR, display, modify);
```

From my understanding `S_IRUSR` should mean there would be only read permission, so why do I get:

> crw------- 1 root root

Also what is the difference between `S_IRUGO` and `S_IRUSR`?

Comment: `S_IRUGO` Is **R**ead for **U**ser, **G**roup and **O**ther. `S_IRUSR` is only for User.

Comment: Use `DEVICE_ATTR_RO()`. It has what you need. Moreover, aliases to permisions are deprecated in the Linux kernel, you need to use octal numbers directly.